# What is continuum in line spectra?

Tags: physical-chemistry, atoms

I read that continuum in line spectra is noticed beyond a certain limit. What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

> The four lines in the visible spectrum (designated by α through δ) were the first observed by Balmer. Notice how the lines crowd together as they approach the ionization limit in the near-ultraviolet part of the spectrum. Once the electron has left the atom, it is in an unbound state and its energy is no longer quantized.
>
> When such electrons return to the atom, they possess random amounts of kinetic energies over and above the binding energy. This reveals itself as the radiation at the short-wavelength end of the spectrum known as the **continuum radiation**.

Source: [Chem1](http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtext/atoms/atpt-3.html)

Answer (score 0):

The energy gap between consecutive orbits(energy levels) decreases as 'n' (energy level) increases. So, the wavelength difference decreases resulting continuum in spectrum.[image]

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning *why* the lines get closer together as energy increases?

Comment: E= -13.6*(1/n^2)

Comment: I mean **change in E** = -13.6*{[1/n^2]-[1/(n+1)^2]}

Comment: Your formula for energy levels is that of hydrogen, but your picture is not.

Comment: That eqn of Energy is for Hydrogen atom. For Hydrogen like species,E =  -13.6*(Z^2)*(1/n^2)

Comment: That's right, so you might want to edit $Z=3$ into your answer.

Comment: This is wrong. The continuum is BEYOND the ionization limit or the series limit, hence is unrelated to 'crowding'. Essentially, continuum is the opposite of quantization (literally a series)